# Why is my report including the column names before every row?

Tags: wordpress, civireport

I am using CiviCRM 5.71.1 with Wordpress. I created a report using the Constituent Report (Detail) template. The issue is that the report repeats the column names before every row of data. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it so that the column names do not repeat?

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: That's how that report displays. There's a distinct section for each contact.

Comment: OK, then how do I get a report without that feature that will list the *multiple* boats owned by each contact?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I used the Constituent Report (Summary) template instead and that gave me the results I needed. I guess I got confused by the names of the templates, assuming that a "Summary" would not give me the individual results.

Comment: Glad you have what you need.  FYI, often its easier now to create a SearchKit than fighting with reports to show what you want.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. I will check out SearchKit.